# Django Admin Not Showing Complete Fields In a Model

Tags: django, django-models, amazon-ec2, django-admin

I am quite new to the Django environment, Here's a problem I am facing:

First I made a model:

```
class ABC(Model):
     field A
     field B
     field C
```

then, I migrated them successfully using the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then, I again added a new field to same model:

```
class ABC(Model):
     #rest fields are here
     field D
```

These also got migrated successfully.

But, Here's the problem now.

After migration, I am not able to see field D in the Django admin interface. (for which I want to edit the value)

AM I missing anything here?

(PS: Have tried sqlflush, dbshell every possible troubleshoot)

I also restarted NGINX & Gunicorn (since I am hosted on AWS EC2)

I am certain, that fields are getting created.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

First, check the `admin.py` file and `admin.ModelAdmin` class of this model.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ABC

@admin.register(ABC)
class ABCAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```